# Auto Resizing in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, autoresizingmask

As I know, before XCode 7 appear, we have Auto Resizing go with Auto Layout (appear in XCode 5), but when XCode 7 appear, Auto Resizing be removed and this appeared again in XCode 8. My question are:

1. Why Apple put back this feature in XCode 8? Do this feature have
   some new functions than previous?
2. We can use Auto Resizing with Auto Layout in the same page. What are
   the benefits of using parallelism like that?

I searched in Apple document but not find info about Auto Resizing
Supply any document link or keyword will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Autoresizing wasn't removed previously, when autolayout was introduced. But in Interface Builder it was available only at the level of the individual *xib* or *storyboard* file: such a file either used exclusively autoresizing or exclusively autolayout. Your views configured in code could use either, but you couldn't mix and match with Interface Builder. The change in Xcode 8 is that now you can: one and the same *xib* or *storyboard* file can contain views some of which use autoresizing and some of which use autolayout (as you rightly say in your point 2).

The advantage is just what you think it is: freedom of choice, plus easy of use: sometimes autoresizing is all you need, and it can be much faster and simpler to configure. For example, if you want a button to be in the top left corner and stay in the top left corner, you just drag a button from the Library into the top left corner and leave it there; the button's autoresizing configuration is top-left by default, and this configuration won't be turned into autolayout constraints, but will simply be left as is.

However, if you then make a constraint *to* that button, you have involved it in autolayout, it will now use autolayout, and you will have to add proper constraints for it. In the past, an autoresizing view was "translated" automatically by Interface Builder into an autolayout view if it became involved in autolayout, with automatically generated "autoresizing constraints", but that no longer happens — and this too is a good thing, as it makes it less likely that you'll end up with an accidental conflict between manual constraints and autoresizing constraints.

Comment: All of this is very well explained in the WWDC 2016 videos, and in future I suggest you take the time to watch them and learn rather than wasting Stack Overflow bandwidth with this sort of stuff.

Comment: thanks for your advise, I think I'm not spend enough time for watch related video in wwdc